# Globally logging jQuery Errors (Event & DOM errors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging, error-handling

Since systems these days are becoming more and more Javascript (jQuery, AJAX, etc) oriented, we've been trying to get more and more Error logging happening for any of these things.

---

**My concern is that within jQuery itself, when normal DOM manipulation / jQuery events are created or executed, `window.onerror` is unable to catch these, and this might help make debugging bugs in production faster, by having them logged on a server**

In this article from 2008 ([.onerror & jQuery bind try/catch{}](http://blogs.cozi.com/techold/2008/04/javascript-erro.html)), they add a **try/catch {}** to the **`jQuery.bind() event`** and even the document.ready event. Now that everything goes through the `.on()` event this article is a bit dated, but I feel like logic could still work...

Has anyone tried implementing such a jQuery overwrite (try/catch system) into their own Projects?

Basically I want to continue using jQuery from the CDN, and just within one of our JS files - extend/override the `.on() / $(document).ready() / etc` events with these changes.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({ // <-- can this be extended / overwritten ?
    on: function(etc etc) {
        // same code just add the additional
        try {
            // try to execute the original .on()
        }
        catch (ex) {
            // log any errors / info (where/why/etc)
        }
    }
});

// or even some sort of try/catch for $(document).ready()?
```

The other typical error logging formats: (of course logging browser/OS/QueryString/etc too)

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
    // Log General Javascript Errors
    // this won't log jQuery internal errors
};

$.ajaxSetup({ // Log AJAX Errors
    error: function (jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) { }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We report JavaScript errors to the server in window.onerror and jQuery ajax errors, without overriding jQuery and it works well. If you want to override a jQuery function, you can do:

```
$.fn.oldOn = $.fn.on;
$.fn.on = function(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
    try {
        $(this).oldOn(a,b,c,d,e,f);
    }
    catch (ex) { ... }
};
```

Comment: Oh great, so you've done try/catch within jQuery events/code? I guess my biggest question was if it's possible to override `.on()` for instance, adding the try/catch, without actually having to edit the jQuery file itself.

Comment: I was probably unclear, sorry. We used error handlers such as you suggest *without* overriding the try/catch and found it worked well. But you can override it if you want. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't even think to set it up like this. Kudos Parched, good looking out. Feel like I got 99% of everything covered now with this addition

Comment: Oh and strange, but check out this fiddle. I can see it entering the try/catch etc, but the actual event alert isn't appearing when it's clicked! http://jsfiddle.net/qbPXP/1/

Comment: Whoops, dumb bug. $(this).oldOn(...), not $.oldOn(...). You need $(this) to set up the 'this' for the new function. http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Jcu/1/

Comment: Works like a charm, you're the man! You should just add these things into your system now since you have the .onerror & ajaxError already!

Comment: Ack. First, that jsfiddle is not testing the catching of errors in the callback. In fact, it's not throwing any errors to be caught. It's testing nothing.Second, this solution doesn't catch errors in the callback. It catches errors while registering the callback. This is pointless. To catch errors in the callback you have to wrap the callback in a try. Third, this discards the return value of $.fn.on, which will break any code that uses method chaining. See ravenjs for an example of wrapping jquery event handlers.

Comment: yup. it's lame. This was a quick response about how one might replace a jquery function with a wrapper, without thought about the error handling part of the question. It has no practical use. Seeing the responses of people who use it, I regret it now, but it's locked in. :(